# jQuery Ajax PHP Array Blank Response No Errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the weird Problem that I get no response from my **Ajax** Call. I get the data but when im trying to return it I only get an blank screen. There are 3 Files in my project which are needed because my project has so many DB calls and functions so its easier to read.

So this one of many functions which calls my ajaxCall function

```
$.when(ajaxCall("getOutlets", '', null)).done(function(res) {
    if(res) {
        console.log(res);
```

this is my global  ajaxCall Function for the whole project:

```
function ajaxCall(functionName, params, answers) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/ajax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            functionIdentifier: functionName, 
            functionParams: params,
        },
```

my Ajax.php file then calls based on the functionName Param the function in my **database.php** file. `Ajax.php`:

```
$response = array();

switch ($functionIdentifier) {
    case 'getOutlets':
        $response = $database->getSearchOutletsFromDatabase($functionParams);
        break;
    .... many switch cases
}

echo json_encode($response);

die();
?>
```

and finally in my database.php It calls the mysqli functions which looks like this:

```
public function getSearchOutletsFromDatabase() {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, "CALL `sp_outlets_get`()") or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));   
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $response[] = $row;
        }

        @mysqli_next_result($this->conn);
            return $response;
        }
```

and here is the weird part. If im returning only one Object from `$result` like return `$result->fetch_object()` I return the first Object successfull. BUT when I just save the row in an array and want to return my array the whole response is empty. No errors. Nothing.

If you need more information just say it Ill try to add more.

**Edit:**
If Im putting this on top of my ajax.php file where the response gets returned I get following error on Developers Network Tab:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $response = array();

    switch ($functionIdentifier) {
        case 'getOutlets':
            $response = $database->getSearchOutletsFromDatabase($functionParams);
            break;
        .... many switch cases
```

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

Comment: Have you looked at the "Network" developer tab to see what's actually being sent and returned?

Comment: why did you put the die() at the end of the php script?

Comment: I get a Status 200 and all looks fine but in Network Tab nothing gets returned. Thats my problem. No Errors. Nothing. Just a white blank screen. But in my Database function if I fetch an object and print it, it has data. Just when I save it in the array and return the array it doesnt work anymore...

Comment: @sietse85 yeah its on the end

Comment: but why did you put it there

Comment: btw put this on top of the script (ajax.php) `header('Content-Type: application/json');` you AJAX call expects JSON to be returned, by default a request does not return this header in PHP you have to set it

Comment: First so my php file doesnt somehow print something after the response, and also for the Ajax function to know when the result is printed and ready to use. But anyway if I would deleted it still same error.

Comment: Edited my QUestion with more Info @sietse85

Comment: what does the response tab say is your json valid ;) from here i think you can figure at the rest, make sure your ajax.php does return valid json, then in your console.log you can dump the object and see whats in there, and maybe adjust your php code accordingly

Comment: :D my bad. But how to slove this? Why should my Json be invalid? I only save the Object `{ id: id, name: name }` into the array?

Comment: also in order to access your variables you should use `$_POST['functionIdentifier']`

Comment: I have that in code. Just didnt show it because this isnt needed. As I mentioned all Functions do work and get data from Database. But somehow only when I save the $row objects into an array and return them it throws this error.

Comment: Have you tried to sent `$row` as is? Why trying to make it an array? Simply try `$response = $row;`

Comment: I have a feeling `$response` is getting overwritten somewhere it shouldn't be. In `getSearchOutletsFromDatabase` could you define a new variable `$var = array();` and push the rows to it and then return it instead and see if your result changes?

Comment: I already tried that. But I finally found the solution and posted it here. It was so simple I didnt see it :D Case closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what caused the error (and sometimes it is one of the easiest things). Well it was `ö,ä,ü` etc in my response. 
Adding a `utf8_encode` before I return my data to ajax solved the problem.

```
public function getSearchOutletsFromDatabase() {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, "CALL `sp_data_get`()") or die(mysqli_error($this->conn));  
    $response = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $res['ID'] = $row['ID'];
        $res['Name'] = utf8_encode($row['Name']);
        array_push($response, $res);
    }
    @mysqli_next_result($this->conn);
    return $response;
}
```